# How can i calculate total sum of uploaded file sizes if there are multiply inputs?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have few inputs inside the form. The task is to disable submit button when total sum of this files sizes more than 60mb.

The only thing i found out for now , that you can count on files[0].size method to get the size of the file. But in my case i have to implement a feature to delete the certain field. As far as i work with event.target method i dont get how can i subtract the size of file the was deleted with the field

Here i created some sandbox to work with

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u1espx

I stucked trying to find the solution how to calculate uploaded files size

Answer (score 0):

You can delete or rather clear the input you want to exclude from the total by adding another element that triggers an event (in this case I use click event), then using template reference of angular, you can pass the input as a reference to that click event listener of the created element and assign its value to empty string, to clear the uploaded file. Also subtract the size to the `totalSum`.

Template:

```
<input type="file" formControlName="first" (change)="onFileUpload($event)" #firstInput> <!-- the `#firstInput` here is the template referencing -->
<span>{{computeSizeInMB(+firstInput.files[0]?.size)}}</span> <!-- added to track the size of uploaded file -->
<span (click)="onClear(firstInput)">clear</span>
```

function inside your Class:

```
onClear(input:HTMLInputElement){
    this.totalSum -= this.computeSizeInMB(+input.files[0].size); //adding `+` to a string 
    input.value = '';
  }

computeSizeInMB(sizeKB:number): number {
    return sizeKB/1024;
  } // method for computing kb to mb
```

Add this somewhere appropriate to your template to verify the total:

```
<div>{{totalSum}}</div><!-- interpolation -->
```

Notes: Please use semicolon for line breaks, also you may want to store the value `1024` as a constant for ease of maintenance and reusability. Try using `let` when declaring variable, I think I read somewhere that when you do not declare properly your variables, JS compiler will declare them as Global variables, not quite sure with TS though, maybe they will just be within the class.

Helpful links: [template referencing, interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

Hope this helps!